# How generate ViewController.h file in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xamarin

I create a new ViewController and renamed class. But still, the .h file where I want to store outlets and action doesn't appear.

Comment: you need to modify the class name from the storyboard or xib file. (aka FileOwner)

Comment: @DeryckLucian I renamed it in Main.storyboard. And didn't find a xib file

Comment: @AlexPark rename the new viewcontroller class name in Identity Inspector and try to click on the right side arrow to verify this is redirecting to the right class

Comment: If you are using Xamarin.iOS it won't appear a .h file as it is an oc file. The file should be named as ViewController.cs in C#. And the outlets could be found in the ViewController.designer.cs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a new view controller and you think files `*your controller name*.h` and `*your controller name*.m` should automatically create. In my case, I start building a project(not in Visual Studio) in XCode. And after that, my files appear.

Answer (score 0):

In your xib or storyboard file change the Class in File's Owner to mach the one you had renamed.

See image:

[image]